# native nodejs mouse and keyboard event listener

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a package for listening mouse and keyboard events system wide.
I am using electron and nodejs.

I tried:

- iohook and it did not work in MacOS (supports macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 and older)
  https://wilix-team.github.io/iohook/os-support.html.
  This doesn't work for Catalina.
- gkm works fine however it needs Java (JVM)
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gkm
  github https://github.com/tomzx/gkm

I did lots of search but did not manage to find any others that will help.

Are there any mouse/keyboard listeners which supports mac/windows new versions; and which does not depend on other languages?

Comment: Shame this still hasn't been addressed. Iohook has been broken for THAT long? I got it to install on Ubuntu 21.04 after editing some scripts, but when trying to use it... I get a segmentation fault!

Answer (score 1):

So since I couldn't find a good alternative nodejs module to iohook that hasn't died off years ago and no longer works... I decided to make my own by updating a fork (which is itself a fork of the OG iohook, lol)

It also has a feature the original didn't... Key code to key name parsing! (Note: Probably only fully works in a US QWERTY layout, but MOST of the keys should be right in any layout)

You can find it here: https://github.com/Pecacheu/node-iohook

Or install it with `npm install iohook2`

Comment: I have been striglling with iohook for 2 days now, cannot make it work on my project, I am making a mac app, so tried your iohook2, but its throwing exact same error as iohook, any direction in which i should start looking ? not sure what to fix, the list is pretty huge